# How to register/load a style css file in a wordpress sub theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

The code that Im using is not changing the login page...

```
function olab_login_stylesheet() 
{
    wp_register_style('olab-login', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/login-style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'olab-login'); 
}   
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'olab_login_stylesheet' );
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `wp_print_styles()` is never called (either directly or via an action) on the login page. If you check out the source of `login_header()`, you'll see the core stylesheets are rendered like so:

```
wp_admin_css( 'wp-admin', true );
wp_admin_css( 'colors-fresh', true );
```

So instead of `wp_enqueue_style( 'olab-login' )`, use `wp_print_styles( 'olab-login' )`, which will output the stylesheet immediately.

And purely for semantics, I would also suggest using the `login_head` action instead, (the two are called one after the other, so there's no *real* difference).

```
function olab_login_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style( 'olab-login', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/login-style.css' );
    wp_print_styles( 'olab-login' );
}

add_action( 'login_head', 'olab_login_stylesheet' );
```

Comment: I've added the complete solution to my answer. Are you sure? Because it works for me!